# How offset are affected when increasing the number of partition for one topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic that has 4 partitions, and I would like to increase to 8 partitions.

I want to know

1. Will the data in the old 4 partitions be evenly balanced to the newly 4 created partitions?
2. How offsets in each partition will be affected,

I am using pull mode to consume the data, I need to know the behavior here so that I could be able to manage offset/find the correct offset to consume in my code when number of partitions are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Existing data is not moved when increasing partitions, therefore offsets are unaffected.

Also, producers will need restarted to detect new partitions and start putting data into them. If your messages have non-null keys and you're expecting messages in a particular order from the partitions, then increasing partitions will temporarily break that guarantee until all old messages from the previous partition count expire